# how to access the ID?

Tags: php, mysql

In the website I'm designing the admin list page shows fields such as Name, Email, Username and Status(whether active or inactive users). My database has a table called **admin**. The fields are *iAdminId, vFirstName, vLastName, vEmail, vUserName, vPassword, vFromIP, vFromIP, dLastLogin, and eStatus*. In the equivalent  PHP page (the admin list page) I am adding an active & inactive button. Check boxes are present with each row. The number of rows that an administrator chooses will be updated(after confirmation, of course) once he/she clicks on *Active* or *Inactive* button.

My javscript code for activation is:

```
function activeRecord()
  {
    var count = getCount();
    if(count == 0)
    {
      alert("Please enter some records for activation first!!");
    }
    else
    {
      var c = confirm("Do you wish to activate?");
      if(c==true)
      {
        document.frm.mode.value="Active";
        document.frm.submit();
      }
      else
      {
        alert("You had wrongly selected 'Active' option!!");
      }
    }
  }
```

getCount returns the number of selected records.
And PHP code is

```
if($mode=="Active")
  {
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ch']);$i++)
    {
      $active = "UPDATE admin SET eStatus = 'Active' WHERE iAdminId = '" . $_POST['ch'][$i] . "'";
      $result = mysql_query($active,$conn);
    }
  }
```

Even after selecting its not deleting the selected records. I tried echoing also.

echo $active = "UPDATE admin SET eStatus = 'Active' WHERE iAdminId = '" . $_POST['ch'][$i] . "'";

"ch" is the array name for all the checkboxes

It shows:
UPDATE admin SET eStatus = 'Inactive' WHERE iAdminId = ''

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

ch is used as:

Pls help. Its urgent. Thanks everybody

Comment: How does your form looks like? It should look like `<input name="ch[0]" value="[the_id]">`. You should sanitize / validate your input too, SQL injection is possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for bothering everybody and loads of thanks for paying the interest in solving my problem.

I guess i needed an extra pair of eyes for checking my code. As @fabsn asked i rechecked my code. I had entered value for the check boxes. So there was no chance of them going blank. It was all just a minor spelling mistake. Its corrected now and working absolutely fine now. I guess i need to be more careful from now onwards so that i dont bother you all unnecessarily.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$_POST['ch']` should be an array. Check if that's true by placing `var_dump($_POST['ch'])` in your PHP script.

Also your checkboxes should use the same name (`<input name="ch[]" value="Element-ID" />`).

There's no need in adding an index in the brackets. If you do so, your for-Loop (which could be replaced by `foreach`) won't work since you're just checking the length and iterate through the array with the wrong keys.

Comment: Check your html source. I guess your checkboxes don't have the correct values. Seems like they all have an empty value (`value=""`)